# Add item to hash went unexpectedly?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

EDIT: My bad!!!Problem solved (I tested this on ruby 1.8, worked as expected on ruby 1.9)

I have an existing hash and wanted to sort it such that all the keys will be in numerical order.

```
a = {4 => 5, 8 => 20, 3 => 2, 6 => 1, 7 => 10, 2 => 1 }
=> #Wanted Newhash = {2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 5, 6 => 1, 7 => 10, 8 => 20 }
```

Here is what I did:

```
b = a.keys.sort => [2,3,4,6,7,8]
c ={}

for key in b
    p key
    c[key] = a[key]
    p c
end
```

Here is the output:

```
2
{2=>1}
3
{2=>1, 3=>2}
4
{2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>5}
6
{6=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>5}
7
{6=>1, 7=>10, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>5}
8
{6=>1, 7=>10, 2=>1, 8=>20, 3=>2, 4=>5}
```

The thing I don't understand is:

The key I sorted in `b` is in order that I wanted. I supposed if I added it to a new hash it would be added to the end of the hash but it wasn't the case here. How so? The key `6` with its value got added in the front and the key `7` got added after that and then key `8` with its value was inserted in between key `2` and `3`. Any explanation?

Comment: which ruby version you are using ?

Comment: I really wouldn't do this. Some versions of Ruby do have a Hash implementation that preserves order, but using a hash as an ordered collection is just always awkward. There is usually a better way to accomplish whatever you wanted to accomplish by ordering the hash.

Comment: The best tactic to force an order to the hash, is to grab the keys, using `keys`, order that array however you want, then use `values_at` to retrieve the associated values in the same order of the keys. That works regardless of the version of Ruby, and that technique is usable across other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you are using Ruby < 1.9. That is the reason you did not get the order you wanted.

Comment: Agreed but why would it happen in 1.8 then?

Comment: @user2393426 Because hash ordering is not guaranteed in Ruby hashes before 1.9. From [the docs for 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html): "The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order." <V.S.> [1.9.1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Hash.html): "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."